# How to type check react navigation nested navigation

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to understand react navigation docs to type check nesting navigators.
This is how my structure looks like.

```
- BottomTabs:
    - HomeStack:
        - Home
        - Details
    - ProfileStack
        - Profile
        - Settings
```

My bottomTab has this type:

```
type BottomTabNavigatorParamsList = {
  homeStack: HomeStackParamsList;
  profileStack: ProfileStackParamsList;
};
```

Each screen of each stack has it's own type too.

I want to navigate from `DetailsScreen` to `SettingsScreen` (from HomeStack to ProfileStack).

I've tried to navigate using the `CompositeNavigationProp` in the `DetailsScreen`:

```
const navigation =
 useNavigation<
   CompositeNavigationProp<
     StackNavigationProp<HomeStackParamsList, "Details">,
     StackNavigationProp<ProfileStackParamsList>
   >
 >();
```

but, if the ProfileStack is not rendered, then I get an exception:

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Settings"} was not
> handled by any navigator.
>
> Do you have a screen named 'Settings'?

If I switch to the Profile tab, before navigating, then go back to the `DetailsScreen` and tap to navigate, then it will work.

Also, using just:

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
navigation.navigate("Settings");
```

will also work, but I get a typescript error check (since I'm not setting useNavigation).

So, basically I want to know how to type check this kind of nesting navigators, I feel like React Navigation docs is not clear at all.

Ref.: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript#nesting-navigators

Does anyone know how to do it?

---

**UPDATE**

If I set the type of the profileStack to `NavigatorScreenParams<ProfileStackParamsList>` I get rid off the typescript error check. The problem I have now is that Profile tab does not get rendered, so when I navigate, I don't have the goback available to navigate to the initial screen (`ProfileScreen` in this case)

Comment: if I understand this correctly, you want typescript to typecheck correctly, or is it a question on functionality? Can you navigate from a HomeStack screen to a profile stack screen? Because you have to use something like ```navigation.navigate("ProfileStack", {screen: "Settings"})``` to reference a nested screen

Comment: When I posted the question, it was a question about how to correctly check navigation types. But, after I could make it after several tries, I faced up with the problem of the stacks that were not rendering since you haven't pressed the tab yet.